# Is this an acceptable question for Stack Overflow? Can I repost from another site?

Tags: discussion, scope, site-recommendation, android

I have a question regarding Android, which wasn't quite programming related so I posted it over at [android.stackexchange.com](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12139/unable-to-access-phone-over-tcp-ip)

But I've discovered the traffic at that site is really slow compared to here and there seems to be a lot more responses to Android related questions here.

Would it be ok to repost the question here or move it here ?

Comment: here, here, here? Where?

Comment: What kind of question is it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12139/unable-to-access-phone-over-tcp-ip) is not a programming question, so no, it would **not** be appropriate to ask it on Stack Overflow.
(In addition, note that *cross-posting* questions on multiple sites is strongly discouraged.)

Questions about using (rather than programming) Android mobile phones belong on the [Android site](https://android.stackexchange.com/). You only asked the question an hour ago—give it a little more time before becoming impatient.

Comment: "strongly discouraged" = "gets deleted, and if enough get deleted you'll get permabanned by the system"

Answer (score 4):

If it's a question about *using* an Android phone (which it appears to be) then you've posted it in the right place.

If it's a question about *programming* for an Android phone then Stack Overflow is the correct site.